# Javascript AJAX timing issue while using jQuery REal Person

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to use jquery Real Person (http://keith-wood.name/realPerson.html). As per the instructions, here is my javascript code. $("#sb1") is the submit button.

I am running into a timing issue, since there's an ajax call involved, where the comment "//bValid is UNDEFINED at this point" is shown, bValid is undefined. Any ideas how I can delay the "bValid = bValid && checkCaptcha();" code so that the ajax call has completed by then?

Thanks, 
Rocket

```
function checkCaptcha() {

  // Call php file to check this

  $.post("ajax/check_captcha.php", { realPerson : $("#defaultReal").val(), realPersonHash: $(".realperson-hash").val()} ,
        function(data) {
        // If data = Error reload page
          if ($.trim(data) == "Error")  {
            updateTips("Captcha does not match");
           return false;
          } else {
            return true;
          }
      });
}
```

...

```
$("#sb1").click(function() {
      var bValid = true;
      bValid = bValid && checkLength($("#title"), "name", 3, 100 );
      bValid = bValid && checkCaptcha(); //bValid is UNDEFINED at this point
      alert("bValid is "+bValid);

      if ( bValid ) {
        setTimeout("$('#submitCampForm').submit();",500);
      }
});
```

The PHP code is unchanged (check_captcha.php).

```
function rpHash($value) {
    $hash = 5381;
    $value = strtoupper($value);
    for($i = 0; $i < strlen($value); $i++) {
        $hash = (leftShift32($hash, 5) + $hash) + ord(substr($value, $i));
    }
    return $hash;
}

// Perform a 32bit left shift
function leftShift32($number, $steps) {
    // convert to binary (string)
    $binary = decbin($number);
    // left-pad with 0's if necessary
    $binary = str_pad($binary, 32, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
    // left shift manually
    $binary = $binary.str_repeat("0", $steps);
    // get the last 32 bits
    $binary = substr($binary, strlen($binary) - 32);
    // if it's a positive number return it
    // otherwise return the 2's complement
    return ($binary{0} == "0" ? bindec($binary) :
        -(pow(2, 31) - bindec(substr($binary, 1))));
}

if (rpHash($_POST['realPerson']) == $_POST['realPersonHash']) {
} else {
  print "Error";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you're returning inside the callback to the ajax function, it's returning its value to the callback function, not the outer function checkCaptcha(). There's no way to make your bValid variable wait until checkCaptcha() has finished, so instead of that, put whatever you wanted to do with your bValid variable inside the ajax function callback, possible like so:

```
$.post("ajax/check_captcha.php", { whatever: whatever} ,function(data) {
    // If data = Error reload page
    if ($.trim(data) == "Error")  {
        updateTips("Captcha does not match");
    } else {
        setTimeout("$('#submitCampForm').submit();",500); //line added
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't ever use a timeout to trust the successful return of a server call, use a callback argument to ensure accurate processes.

```
function checkCaptcha(CB){
  $.post(
    "file",
    options,
    function(data) {
      if($.trim(data) == "Error")  {
        updateTips("Captcha does not match");
        CB && CB(false);
      }else{
        CB && CB(true);
      }
    }
  );
}

$('#sb1').click(function(){
  checkCaptcha(function(status){
    if(status){
      // captcha true
    }else{
      // captcha false
    }
  });
});
```

Obviously I left out some parts of your code that would be irreverent to others viewing this page, so you'd have to put those back in, but the "jist" is all there...

Also, just a side note, but I'd personally prefer the actual [Captcha](http://www.captcha.net/) API instead. Not only is it more secure, but it also is a quite amazing utility that helps digitize old texts at the same time. Nothing against the one your using but it seems very hackable.